# UWP Change ListView Item Height

Tags: listview, win-universal-app, uwp, listviewitem

How do you change the height of items in a ListView control in a Windows 10 UWP app?

For example in UWP, the following does not make the row height 20. (WPF questions might suggest this, but it does not seem to work in the UWP XAML):

```
        <ListView x:Name="listView" IsItemClickEnabled="True">
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="20" />
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Height="20">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Foreground="White" Height="20"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to also set the `MinHeight` property:

```
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="20" />
                <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="20" />
            </Style>
```

Comment: Nowadays remove the Height property.

Answer (score 4):

You can also override the style of your data template.

```
<Page.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Default">
                <x:Double x:Key="ListViewItemMinHeight">20</x:Double>
                <x:Double x:Key="ListViewItemHeight">20</x:Double>
            </ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="HighContrast">
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Page.Resources>
```

http://loekvandenouweland.com/content/UWP-lightweight-listview-styling.html